# Is there a way to read a JSON with Julia efficiently if you know exactly what the layout of the JSON will be?

Tags: json, parsing, julia, allocation

I have a websocket which reads data that I parse into JSON files. I currently use JSON3.parse, and then convert each field into the form I want, which causes a lot of allocations and takes time.

The format of the JSON is a dictionary which is laid out like this:

1. Key1: A dictionary that I do not care about (and would ignore if I could)
2. Key2: A string which decides how I process the rest of the JSON
3. Key3: A Vector of size 1 which contains a dictionary which contains:

   ```
    3a. Key3.1: A Vector of Vectors of length 4, containing numbers in string format (that I need to parse into numbers). I only need the first 2 numbers in each of these vectors of length 4.
    3b. Key3.2: Same format as Key3.1
    3c. Key3.3: Timestamp in nanos
    3d. Key3.4: A number I don't need
   ```

I've looked at using JSON3 and OrderedStruct/StructTypes to efficiently do this, but I am having a hard time.

The original data is in UInt8 format, this is what I get after parsing.

```
{       
      "arg": {
                "channel": "books50-l2-tbt",
                 "instId": "FIL-USD-210618" 
             },
   "action": "snapshot",
     "data": [
               {
                      "asks": [
                                [
                                  "69.604",
                                  "100",   
                                  "0",     
                                  "1"      
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.624",
                                  "27",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.63",
                                  "946",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.728",
                                  "302",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.729",
                                  "1731",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.744",
                                  "140",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.79",
                                  "498",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.791",
                                  "3015",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.841",
                                  "50",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "70.006",
                                  "5081",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "70.02",
                                  "5129",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "70.199",
                                  "29",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "70.224",
                                  "3063",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "70.262",
                                  "68",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "70.549",
                                  "39",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "70.901",
                                  "22",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.06",
                                  "2047",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.255",
                                  "43",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.399",
                                  "37",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.498",
                                  "1972",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.611",
                                  "21",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.711",
                                  "2033",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.755",
                                  "49",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "71.969",
                                  "32",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "72.113",
                                  "32",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "72.328",
                                  "43",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "72.473",
                                  "22",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "72.689",
                                  "25",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "72.835",
                                  "50",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "73.052",
                                  "34",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "73.199",
                                  "31",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "73.224",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "73.564",
                                  "24",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "73.931",
                                  "44",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "74.3",
                                  "36",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "76.885",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "80.729",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "84.765",
                                  "3",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "89.003",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "93.453",
                                  "1",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "98.125",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "103.031",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "108.182",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "113.591",
                                  "1",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ]
                              ],
                      "bids": [
                                [
                                  "69.47",
                                  "63",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.469",
                                  "100",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.419",
                                  "50",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.336",
                                  "70",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.335",
                                  "70",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.273",
                                  "302",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.272",
                                  "1290",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.254",
                                  "498",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.253",
                                  "3015",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.219",
                                  "50",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.217",
                                  "120",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.207",
                                  "70",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.179",
                                  "67",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.136",
                                  "70",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.134",
                                  "160",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "69.034",
                                  "4685",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "68.942",
                                  "55",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "68.744",
                                  "5101",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "68.742",
                                  "74",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "68.619",
                                  "3008",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "68.399",
                                  "104",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "68.058",
                                  "81",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "67.915",
                                  "1973",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "67.718",
                                  "109",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "67.593",
                                  "2034",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "67.38",
                                  "103",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "67.184",
                                  "2038",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "67.044",
                                  "57",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "66.709",
                                  "71",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "66.376",
                                  "101",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "66.252",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "66.045",
                                  "59",
                                  "0",
                                  "2"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "62.94",
                                  "1",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "59.793",
                                  "3",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "56.804",
                                  "3",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "53.964",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "51.266",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "48.703",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "46.268",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "43.955",
                                  "2",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ],
                                [
                                  "41.758",
                                  "1",
                                  "0",
                                  "1"
                                ]
                              ],
                        "ts": "1623570748052",
                  "checksum": 599613499
               }
             ]
}
```

Comment: I think you're basically looking for an event-based parser, like SAX for XML. They seem to be somewhat rare, though...

Comment: Are you running into actual performance problems? The `JSON3` docs (https://quinnj.github.io/JSON3.jl/stable/#Read-and-write-from/to-a-file) say that they're efficient: "... a semi-lazy parsing of JSON to the JSON3.Object or JSON3.Array types. The technique involves using a type-less "tape" to note the positions of objects, arrays, and strings in a JSON structure, while avoiding the cost of materializing such objects. ... enables efficiencies in workflows where only small pieces of a JSON structure are needed, because expensive objects, arrays, and strings aren't materialized unless accessed."